# How to use a function on onClick instead of onChange?

Tags: reactjs, jsx

i have an search function for searching in the table. Now. I want to use the search function on the onClick of the icon instead of the onChange of the input field. I don't think i need the throttle for that. I try to use the function setGlobalFilter directly inside the handleClick but it won't work

```
function GlobalFilter({ globalFilter, setGlobalFilter }) {
  const [value, setValue] = React.useState(globalFilter)
  const onChange = React.useCallback(
    value => {
      const throttledSetGlobalFilter = throttle(
        value => {
          setGlobalFilter(value || undefined)
        },
        2000
      )
      throttledSetGlobalFilter(value)
    },
    [setGlobalFilter]
  )
  return (
    <span className={styles.componentGlobalFilter}>
      <input
        className={styles.input}
        value={value || ''}
        onChange={(e) => {
          setValue(e.target.value)
          onChange(e.target.value)
        }}
        placeholder={`Zoek in deze tabel`}
      />
      <Icon onClick={handleClick} layoutClassName={styles.icon} {...{ icon }} />
    </span>
  )
  function handleClick() {

  }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean it doesn't work? Could you be a bit more specific? In your code, `handleClick` does not call `setGlobalFilter`.

Comment: What exactly isn't working? Add `setGlobalFilter(value)` to the `handleClick` callback? You will still want the onChange handler to update local component state.

Comment: I mean i fired the function `setGlobalFilter(value || undfined)` directly in the function handleClick. But that doesn't work correctly

Comment: @DrewReese i know i have to keep the onChange, but the onChange is the function `setGlobalFilter`. So everytime i change the input field the onChange function fires itself. But he has to fire itself only when i click the icon with the function handleClick

Comment: No, in the `handleClick` callback. Sounds like you want to use `handleClick` to send data back out to parent. You'll still need the `onChange` handler to update local state. Remove the `setGlobalFilter` call in the `onChange` handler.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question, you want the icon click to invoke the `setGlobalFilter` callback with the input value. Remove the `onChange` handler and directly update value state. Call `setGlobalFilter` with the state value when the icon is clicked.

```
function GlobalFilter({ globalFilter, setGlobalFilter }) {
  const [value, setValue] = useState(globalFilter ?? '');

  const handleClick = () => setGlobalFilter(value);

  return (
    <span className={styles.componentGlobalFilter}>
      <input
        className={styles.input}
        value={value}
        onChange={(e) => setValue(e.target.value)}
        placeholder={`Zoek in deze tabel`}
      />
      <Icon onClick={handleClick} layoutClassName={styles.icon} {...{ icon }} />
    </span>
  );
}
```

If you need to throttle the `setGlobalFilter` then the following may help.

```
function GlobalFilter({ globalFilter, setGlobalFilter }) {
  const [value, setValue] = useState(globalFilter ?? '');

  const handleClick = throttle(
    () => setGlobalFilter(value),
    2000,
  );

  return (
    <span className={styles.componentGlobalFilter}>
      <input
        className={styles.input}
        value={value}
        onChange={(e) => setValue(e.target.value)}
        placeholder={`Zoek in deze tabel`}
      />
      <Icon onClick={handleClick} layoutClassName={styles.icon} {...{ icon }} />
    </span>
  );
}
```